# Are advaitha peetadhipathis necessarily jivan mukthas?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, india

Is it mandatory that the Peetadhipathi of Advaitha Peetas has to be liberated?

Comment: Those who opted for closing. Please understand it again. I am asking for a statement saying that Jivan muktha state is mandatory for a person to become peetadipathi. If there is no such statement then it is not necessary.

Comment: There is no objective way to know if a person is jIvanmukta and some schools dont even believe in that concept.

Comment: @yAdRcchika Advaitha school has jivanmuktha concept and the peethas I am asking for are the advaitha peethas only. A Jivan muktha can classify another person as jivan muktha or not.  But my question is not subjective.

Comment: I am not convinced. I think it it is opinion based. But I will retract my close vote.

Comment: May be or may not be. Everything depends upon the prArabdha of the bodies that the souls of Acharyas live in. 
The post of peethadhipati demands certain level of scholarship,  certain norms to be followed, etc. The foremost acharya of advaita Sri Chandrasekharendra Swamy of Kanchi mutt remained mathadhipathi.  Swami Vivekananda established Ramakrishna mission, which also advocates Advaita.  However, their way of functioning may be different from that of Kanchi mutt. Further, liberation may not be a prerequisite for one to become a peethadhipati of any type of sect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes; in short the answer is YES.**

The peethadhipatis of any of the four mathas; Should be knower of Supreme self.
When Adi Shankara (507-475 B.C.) established the four AmnAy Peethas (the monasteries) in four directions of Bharat Varsh (India) He also wrote a set of rules or constitution for working of these Mathas; called **Mathaamnay Setu or Mahanushasanam** .

You can download the English translation of this book by Parameshvar Nath Mishra [here](https://archive.org/details/MathamnayaSetuShardaBhasya).

In any case; I'l point out the relevant parts of the book here

> A Complete renouncer of extreme stage(Samnyasi) who is endowed with external and
>   internal purity; conquorer of all organs; proficient in Vedas, its
>   subsidiaries, in all scriptures, **knower of the supreme self** and is
>   **ever established in his own self**, may occupy the place .{48}
>
> Excellent complete renouncer enriched with aforesaid supreme knowledge
>   may inherit my seat otherwise inspite of being ascended he is **liable
>   to be removed by the omniscient lords, i.e. Shankaracharyas of other
>   three seats**.{49}

**However there might be no way for normal people to know if a particular Samnyasi is JeevanMUkt or not. So it is not necessary that Shankaracharya of a particular Peetha is JeevanMukt but we know that; it is at least the benchmark set by Adi Shankara**